# TypeScript typed array usage

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a TypeScript class definition that starts like this;

```
module Entities {          

    export class Person {
        private _name: string;
        private _possessions: Thing[];
        private _mostPrecious: Thing;

        constructor (name: string) {
            this._name = name;
            this._possessions = new Thing[100];
        }
```

Looks like an array of type Thing does not get translated correctly to the corresponding Javascript array type.  This is a snippet from the generated JavaScript:

```
function Person(name) {
    this._name = name;
    this._possessions = new Entities.Thing[100]();
}
```

Executing code containing a Person object, throw an exception when attempting to initialize the _possession field:

> Error is "0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '100': object is null or undefined".

If I change the type of _possession to `any[]`  and initialize _possession with `new Array()` exception is not thrown.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax here:

```
this._possessions = new Thing[100]();
```

This doesn't create an "array of things". To create an array of things, you can simply use the array literal expression:

```
this._possessions = [];
```

Of the array constructor if you want to set the length:

```
this._possessions = new Array(100);
```

I have created a brief working example you can try in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20Entities%20%7B%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Thing%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20_name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20_possessions%3A%20Thing%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20_mostPrecious%3A%20Thing%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%20%28name%3A%20string%29%20%7B%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._possessions%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._possessions.push%28new%20Thing%28%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._possessions%5B100%5D%20%3D%20new%20Thing%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

```
module Entities {  

    class Thing {

    }        

    export class Person {
        private _name: string;
        private _possessions: Thing[];
        private _mostPrecious: Thing;

        constructor (name: string) {
            this._name = name;
            this._possessions = [];
            this._possessions.push(new Thing())
            this._possessions[100] = new Thing();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not fix the length, but rather should preallocate the array

Comment: why can't you do `private _possessions: Thing[] : []; ` in the class definition?

Answer (score 59):

There are two syntax options available when declaring an array in typescript. The [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) uses `Array<T>` however ts-lint prefers `T[]`

By using the `Array<Thing>` it is making use of the generics in typescript. It is similar to asking for a `List<T>` in c# code.

```js
// Declare with default value
private _possessions: Array<Thing> = new Array<Thing>(); // or
private _possessions: Array<Thing> = []; // or
private _possessions: Thing[] = []; // or -> prefered by ts-lint
```

**or**

```js
// declare then assign in the constructor
private _possessions: Array<Thing>; // or
private _possessions: Thing[]; // or -> preferd by ts-lint
  
constructor(){
    this._possessions = new Array<Thing>(); // or
    this._possessions = []; // or
}
```

Comment: To preallocate the size, use `new Array<Thing>(100)`.

Comment: you can also use ... <Thing> []

Comment: @danday74 - I have updated to include your method, it is the default when using ts-lint recomended / latest config.

Answer (score 10):

The translation is correct, the typing of the expression isn't. TypeScript is incorrectly typing the expression `new Thing[100]` as an array. It should be an error to index `Thing`, a constructor function, using the index operator. In C# this would allocate an array of 100 elements. In JavaScript this calls the value at index 100 of `Thing` as if was a constructor. Since that values is `undefined` it raises the error you mentioned. In JavaScript and TypeScript you want `new Array(100)` instead.

You should report this as a bug on CodePlex.

Comment: I do not want new Array(100).  I want a typed array of Thing.  I do not know if this is a bug or just my misinterpretation of the document spec.