# Creating an array of a class Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I need to create an array of a class using Angular 2 and TypeScript.

```
import { ClassX } from '...';    

public ListX: ClassX[];
```

Once I have the list, I want to then add more empty instances of `ClassX`

```
action() {
  this.ListX.push(ClassX);
}
```

This would then add a new `ClassX` instance to the front end

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870291/typescript-typed-array-usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but adding a new instance of something usually includes using the keyword `new` like this:

```js
this.ListX.push(new ClassX());
```

And instantiation of an array is done like so:

```js
public ListX: ClassX[] = [];
```

or:

```js
public ListX: Array<ClassX> = new Array<ClassX>();
```

While I prefer the latter, since it's more clear, what is happening.