# Angular4 using a collection of object

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular4 and I don't know how to declare a collection of objects and then adding an item and removing an item ?
Thanks for your help

Here is what did :
The Component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    // tableaux d'objets
    personnes: Object[]=[{id:1, nom: "Alain"},{id: 2, nom: "Clémentine"},{id: 3, nom: "Cathy"}];
}
```

The template :

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let personne of personnes">
        <td>{{personne.id}}</td>
        <td>{{personne.nom}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It works fine, but now I would want to manage my collection of objects, for instance the user will provide datas and I'll create a new object with those datas and I'll add this new object to my collection.
I tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
personnes: Object[] = [];
personne: any = {{id:1, nom: "Alain"};
this.personnes.push(this.personne);
```

or

```
personnes: any[] = [];
personne: any = {{id:1, nom: "Alain"};
this.personnes.push(this.personne);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870291/typescript-typed-array-usage google is your best friend

Comment: In what context... http get, *ngFor, other?

Comment: Please specify "a collection of objects" more detailed. What does a object look like? And what do you want to do with the collection?

Comment: hi just use as array of any , I would suggest to check documentation for this in the official site in (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) , this is a test using you example http://plnkr.co/edit/vsQWITwK48beVWVCiiAI?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

hi just use as array of any , I would suggest to check documentation for this in the official site in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html , this it is a test using your example http://embed.plnkr.co/vsQWITwK48beVWVCiiAI/

Comment: hello, thanks for your solution wich works fine if I fire it as it but doesn't works if I create an angular project with anglar CLI (ng new prj-collection) and I copy/paste your code. Here is the first line of the errors messages : ERROR in M:/angular4/prj-collection/src/app/app.component.ts (9,31): Type '{ id: number; nom: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'any[][]'. Type '{ id: number; nom: string; }' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'any[]'... It misses that a reference, but which ?

Comment: Hi @NicolasAlain just remove [] from Array<any>, like that " personnes: Array<any>=[{id:1, nom: "Alain"},{id: 2, nom: "Clémentine"},{id: 3, nom: "Cathy"}]; "

Comment: Wonderfull ! You are the best ;-)