# Initializing an array of a class : Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to initialize an array of a class in angular 5.

```
export class B{

  public Colors: string;
  public Temp: number;
  public Numbers: number;

}

export class A{

  public MyTable: B[];
  public othervar: number;
  ...
  ...
}
```

Then I try to initialize MyTable like that:

```
var test = new A();

test.MyTable[0].Numbers = 25;
test.MyTable[0].Colors= "blue";
```

Is this correct ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript typed array usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870291/typescript-typed-array-usage)

Answer (score 1):

You also have new use `new B()`:

```
const test = new A();

test.MyTable = [];
test.MyTable[0] = new B();
test.MyTable[0].Numbers = 25;
test.MyTable[0].Colors= "blue";
```

Comment: I did that, but then my whole html component is messed up. When ever I try to play with that array nothing in my html component is being displayed. I have interpolations in there and none of them works as soon as I do anything with test.MyTable array...

Comment: Can you post that HTML? There's no reason adding proper initialization of a class instance should, in and of itself, mess anything up.

Comment: I added a line to also initialize the array.

Comment: Here a live test of my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntwkai?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You have `<table>` markup around something which isn't a table -- that's just going to be invisible. I changed it to a `<div>` just to see what was going on. <div> Of the markup inside that `div`, only `{{_types.MyTable[0].Colors }}` made sense for your class -- the rest was causing errors.

Comment: even with a table it works. I see my error I had some interpolations error just before the correct one so it was not displaying.

Comment: So basically my mistake was that I was missing this part: test.MyTable = [];

Thank you for your help.